# Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, winforms

I get error message:

> Parameter is not valid.

from this line:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
```

Here my drawing function:

```
private int mouseIndex = -1;

private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Index == -1) return;

  Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
  if (e.Index > -1)
  {
    if (e.Index == mouseIndex)
    {
      e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.HotTrack, e.Bounds);
      textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
    }
    else
    {
      if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
      {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
        textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
      }
      else
      {
        // This Line:
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
      }
    }
     e.Graphics.DrawString(contact.P_DISPLAYNAME, 
     e.Font, textBrush, e.Bounds.Left + 20, e.Bounds.Top);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the rest of your code? What are you truing to do?

Comment: A little more context would increase your changes for a good solution.

Comment: I try to drawItem, but message point to this line,

I want to put my code, where can I put it the same my question.

Comment: you can click edit link and update the question

Comment: Anyone help me, I posted my code above and get error Parameter is not valid!, at This line : that put in code.

Comment: this is my e.Bounds value: {X=0,Y=52,Width=251,Height=13}

Comment: You have to post code that reproduces the problem.  This code currently works.  I suspect there is more code, because you currently aren't drawing any text.

Comment: I will post the text that I drawed  at above code

Answer (score 0):

You give too little information. Probably e.Bounds is not a valid rectangle. (Rectangle is 0 or null).

Comment: Actually, I used to used this code to drawItem, it is working when I add object class in to ListBox, but now my data is json, and I used foreach to read json index then add ListBox.items.add(data)

And then, I DrawItem.

Is possible or not between data object and json in ListBox to make error?

Comment: It could be that the inserted data is null. (Perhaps you have done a wrong JSON conversion)

Comment: How should I read Json to easy to put in ListBox?

my json like that data[{name="...",email ="..."},{name="...",email="..."}]

Comment: I suggest to ask a new question with more information and source samples.